# R assigning function call to two different cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing

So far, all I've read about parallel processing in R involves looking at multiple rows of one dataframe.

But what if I have 2 or three large dataframes that I want to perform a long function on? Can I assign each instance of the function to a specific core so I don't have to wait for it to work sequentially? I'm on windows.

Lets say this is the function:

```
AltAlleleRecounter <- function(names,data){
data$AC <- 0
numalleles <- numeric(length=nrow(data))
for(i in names){
    genotype <- str_extract(data[,i],"^[^/]/[^/]")
    GT <- dstrfw(genotype,c('character','character','character'),c(1L,1L,1L))
    data[GT$V1!='.',]$AC <- data[GT$V1!='.',]$AC+GT[GT$V1!='.',]$V1+GT[GT$V1!='.',]$V3
    numalleles[GT$V1!='.'] <- numalleles[GT$V1!='.'] + 2
}
data$AF <- data$AC/numalleles
return(data)
}
```

What I want to do is basically this (generic psuedocode):

```
wait_till_everything_is_finished(
core1="data1 <- AltAlleleRecounter(sampleset1,data1,1)",
core2="data2 <- AltAlleleRecounter(sampleset2,data2,2)",
core3="data3 <- AltAlleleRecounter(sampleset3,data3,3)"
)
```

where all three commands are running but the program doesn't progress until everything is done.

Edit:
Bryan's suggestion worked. I replaced "otherList" with my second list. This is example code:

```
myframelist <- list(data1,data2)
mynameslist <- list(names1,names2)
myframelist <- foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% (AltAlleleRecounter(mynameslist[[i]],myframelist[[i]]))
myfilenamelist <- list("data1.tsv","data2.tsv")
foreach(i=1:2) %dopar% (write.table(myframelist[[i]], file=myfilenamelist[[i]], quote=FALSE, sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE))
```

The data variables are dataframes and the name variables are just character vectors. You may need to reload some packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl<-makeCluster(6) ## you can set up as many cores as you need/want/have here. 
registerDoParallel(cl)
getDoParWorkers() # should be the number you registered. If not, something went wrong.

df1<-data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
df2<-data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
df3<-data.frame(matrix(1:9, ncol = 3))
mylist<-list(df1, df2, df3)

otherList<-list(1, 2, 3)

mylist<-foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% (mylist[[i]] * otherList[[i]])
mylist

[[1]]
X1 X2 X3
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9

[[2]]
X1 X2 X3
2  8 14
4 10 16
6 12 18

[[3]]
X1 X2 X3
3 12 21
6 15 24
9 18 27
```

I do this fairly often with topic modeling different databases. The idea is to create lists of the data you want to apply your function to, then have `foreach` apply your function to those indexed lists in parallel. For your example you will have to make a list of your `data.frames` and another list of your samplesets.

Comment: Probably the most directly helpful answer I've received. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, my loaded libraries aren't being recognized in parallel processing, even if I export the global environment, so I have to load them again in the function, but it works.

Comment: You can add the argument `.packages = foo` within the `foreach` call and it will load your libraries onto each core.